# $E_\infty$-algebras and Tor-unital rings

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, operads

Recall that a non-unital ring $R$ is called Tor-unital if $Tor^1_{R_+}(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z) \cong 0$ where $R_+$ is the unitalization of $R$. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.04998.pdf. If $R$ is Tor-unital, does $\bigsqcup_n BGL_n(R)$ have a natral $E_\infty$-algebra structure?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tor-unital rings, but the E_∞-structure of $\coprod_n BGL_n(R)$ is secretly coming from the tensor product of $R$-modules. Do you know if modules over a (commutative?) Tor-unital ring have a tensor product? And how are you defining $GL_n(R)$ for a non-unital ring?

Comment: Don’t we usually use the direct sum, not the tensor product?

Comment: @DylanWilson I guess I interpreted "E_∞-algebra" as "E_∞-ring" structure (mainly because the direct sum structure is always there for trivial reasons), but you're right, the OP might just mean that. Although in that case I don't understand why the Tor-unitality is relevant.

Comment: If the ring is not unital, the category of $R$ modules with direct sum might not be symmetric monoidal so $\sqcup BGL_n(R)$ might not be an $E_\infty$-algebra in spaces. $GL_n(R)$ of a non-unital ring can be thought of as a congruence subgroup. In particular, it might not contain the symmetric group on $n$ letters which is needed to prove that the category of $R$-modules to be symmetric monoidal. Possibly Tor unitality will imply that in some derived sense, $GL_n(R)$ contains the symmetric group. Tor unitality is equivalent to excision in algebraic $K$-theory.

Comment: One way to define $GL_n(R)$ for a non-unital ring is to realize $R$ as an ideal in a unital ring $K$ and let $GL_n(R)$ be the kernel of the map $GL_n(K) \to GL_n(K/R)$. This is independent of the ring $K$. $K$ exists as there is a unital ring structure on $R \oplus \mathbb Z$ for any non-unital ring $R$.